# vnode and file descriptor in xnu, where does the file operation vector is stored

Tags: c, macos, driver, kernel-extension, xnu

In xnu we have the `vnode_t` entity which represent the file globally.

Each process can access the file (assuming it has right permissions) by setting new file descriptor and set the vnode under fg_data

```
fp->f_fglob->fg_data = vp;
```

the vnode contain a list of basic actions for all relevant operations and is set in according to the file's FS. i.e. HFS+ driver implement such vector and set its vnode accordingly.

```
int     (**v_op)(void *);       /* vnode operations vector */
```

this is a vector for function pointers for all actions that may operate on the vnode.

In addition, we have the fileops struct that is part of the file descriptor (fg_global) which describe a minimal subset of these functions:

Here is a typical definition :

```
const struct fileops vnops = {
 .fo_type = DTYPE_VNODE,
 .fo_read = vn_read,
 .fo_write = vn_write,
 .fo_ioctl = vn_ioctl,
 .fo_select = vn_select,
 .fo_close = vn_closefile,
 .fo_kqfilter = vn_kqfilt_add,
 .fo_drain = NULL,
};
```

and we set it here :

```
fp->f_fglob->fg_ops = &vnops;
```

I saw that when reading regular file under local filesystem (HFS+), it works through the file_descriptor and not the vnode ...

```
 * frame #0: 0xffffff801313c67c kernel`vn_read(fp=0xffffff801f004d98, uio=0xffffff807240be70, flags=0, ctx=0xffffff807240bf10) at vfs_vnops.c:978 [opt]
frame #1: 0xffffff801339cc1a kernel`dofileread [inlined] fo_read(fp=0xffffff801f004d98, uio=0xffffff807240be70, flags=0, ctx=0xffffff807240bf10) at kern_descrip.c:5832 [opt]
frame #2: 0xffffff801339cbff kernel`dofileread(ctx=0xffffff807240bf10, fp=0xffffff801f004d98, bufp=140222138463456, nbyte=282, offset=<unavailable>, flags=<unavailable>, retval=<unavailable>) at sys_generic.c:365 [opt]
frame #3: 0xffffff801339c983 kernel`read_nocancel(p=0xffffff801a597658, uap=0xffffff801a553cc0, retval=<unavailable>) at sys_generic.c:215 [opt]
frame #4: 0xffffff8013425695 kernel`unix_syscall64(state=<unavailable>) at systemcalls.c:376 [opt]
frame #5: 0xffffff8012e9dd46 kernel`hndl_unix_scall64 + 22
```

My question is why does this duality needed, and in which cases the operation works through the file_descriptor vector (fg_ops) and which cases the operation works through the vnode vector (vp->v_op).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] in which cases the
>   operation works through the file_descriptor vector (fg_ops) and which
>   cases the operation works through the vnode vector (vp->v_op).

I'm going to start by answering this second part of the question first: if you trace through your call stack further, and look inside the `vn_read` function, you'll find that it contains this line:

```
    error = VNOP_READ(vp, uio, ioflag, ctx);
```

The `VNOP_READ` function (kpi_vfs.c) in turn has this:

```
_err = (*vp->v_op[vnop_read_desc.vdesc_offset])(&a);
```

So the answer to your question is that for your typical file, **both** tables are used for dispatching operations.

With that out of the way,

> My question is why does this duality needed […]

Not everything to which a process can hold a file descriptor is also represented in the file system. For example, pipes don't necessarily have to be named. A vnode doesn't make any sense in that context. So in sys_pipe.c, you'll see a different fileops table:

```
static const struct fileops pipeops = {
    .fo_type = DTYPE_PIPE,
    .fo_read = pipe_read,
    .fo_write = pipe_write,
    .fo_ioctl = pipe_ioctl,
    .fo_select = pipe_select,
    .fo_close = pipe_close,
    .fo_kqfilter = pipe_kqfilter,
    .fo_drain = pipe_drain,
};
```

Similar deal for sockets.

File descriptors track the state of a process's view of a file or object that allows file-like operations. Things like position in the file, etc. - different processes can have the same file open, and they must each have their own read/write position - so vnode:fileglob is a 1:many relationship.

Meanwhile, using vnode objects to track things other than objects within a file system doesn't make any sense either. Additionally, the v_op table is file system specific, whereas vn_read/VNOP_READ contain code that applies to any file that's represented in a file system.

So in summary they're really just different layers in the I/O stack.

Comment: Hi and thanks. just one more thing. following your response, I did some more research on that matter and found out that VNOP_READ calls `hfs_vop_read` which is part of HFS+ driver, which itself calls the cluster method of `cluster_read` which actually does all the low-level read (from cache or from disk) .. so far so good, however, I couldn't find the synonym in `mmap` which calls VNOP_MMAP that calls `hfs_vnop_mmap`, but in this function, which return ENOTSUP "because we want the cluster layer
to actually do all the real work." (quoted from their comment)...

Comment: this leaves me with the question of who's in charge of reading the file in mmap case. of course it's the cluster layer, but who calls `cluster_read` or something similar from mmap call trace ?